# Неправильная работа модуля random python

Tags: python, csv, случайные-числа

**Суть кода: считывание имён пользователей из csv файла.**

Вот так код работает идеально (считывание имен происходит правильно и вся нужная информация выводится):

```
import csv, random
with open ("members.csv", newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        users = row['username']
        print(users)
```

Но когда я добавляю одну строку с рандомным выбором имени пользователя, то выводятся просто строки с рандомными одиночными буквами, которые не имеют никакого отношения к именам пользователей (к примеру: d w t)

```
import csv, random
with open ("members.csv", newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        users = row['username']
        user1 = random.choice(users)
        print(user1)
```

С чем может быть это связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это связано с тем что вы выбираете случайную букву из **строки** `users`.

`users` - у вас является строкой со значением из столбца `username` **для текущей строки цикла**.

Возможно вы хотели сделать что-то подобное:

```
import csv, random

users = []
with open ("members.csv", newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        users.append(row['username'])

random_user = random.choice(users)
print(random_user)
```